# Can we add clickAction in visNetwork() like this: visNetwork(MisNodes, MisLinks, clickAction = Myclickaction)

Tags: r, visnetwork

I want to change nodes shape for that reason I am using **visNetwork()** instead of **forceNetwork()**. But In visNetwork clickAction is not working. Here is my code:

```
install.packages("visNetwork")
require(visNetwork, quietly = TRUE)
library(visNetwork)

shapes <- c("square", "triangle", "box", "circle", "dot", "star",
            "ellipse", "database", "text", "diamond")
set.seed(1)
MisNodes$shape <- sample(shapes, nrow(MisNodes), replace=TRUE)


Myclickaction = 'window.open("https://www.google.com/", "_blank")'
visNetwork(MisNodes, MisLinks, clickAction = Myclickaction)


Myclickaction = 'window.open("https://www.linkedin.com/feed/", "_blank")'
visNetwork(MisNodes, MisLinks, clickAction = Myclickaction)
```

I passes clickAction in visNetwork but It is not working. I am not sure whether we can pass "clickAction" in visNetwork() or not. Thank you in advance